# Ground/short circuit confusion

Tags: gain

I am reading the book Electronic Principles by Malvino and I found the circuit shown below.
It asks to find the A(gain) when the switch is in position 1 and in position 2.

I am not sure about this but in position 1 I found that A = 10k/10k + 1 = 2.

What about position 2?
[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this online schematic drawing tool, please: [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding on to Dave's answer,

An ideal op-amp follows two basic rules when operating under closed-loop feedback conditions:

1. The voltage at the two inputs are equal
2. There is no current flowing into or out of the op-amp inputs

**Position 1:**
[image: pos1]

In position 1, the voltage at the bottom input is `Vin`. Using rule 1, the voltage at node `A` is also `Vin`.

Since there's no voltage difference across the left resistor, there's no current flowing in. Using Kirchoff's current law,

\begin{equation}
\sum{I_A} = 0
\end{equation}

Since there is no current from `Vin` to node `A` and since the op-amp input can't source/sink any current, that must mean there is also no current flowing from node `A` to  `Vout`, thus `Vout = VA = Vin`. This means the gain is `1`.

**Position 2:**
[image: pos2]

Here, the two op-amp inputs are set to `0V` (due to rule 1). The current flowing from `Vin` to node `A` is thus:

\begin{equation}
I = \frac{Vin}{R}
\end{equation}

Again, the op-amp input sources/sinks no current so that means the current flowing from node `A` to `Vout` is:

\begin{equation}
I = \frac{0 - Vout}{R} = \frac{Vin}{R}
\end{equation}

Solving for `Vout`, we get
\begin{equation}
Vout = -Vin
\end{equation}

Thus getting the output gain of `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm assuming that the upper input to the opamp is the inverting input.)

Keep in mind that an opamp with negative feedback works to keep its input pins at the same voltage.

- With the switch in position "1", the amplifier is configured as a unity-gain buffer. Gain = +1.0

In this configuration, the actual values of the resistors don't matter, as long as the left-hand resistor isn't zero (shorted) and the right-hand resistor isn't infinite (open). There's never any voltage across either resistor, since both the output and the inverting input track the voltage on the noninverting input.

- With the switch in position "2", the amplifier is configured as an inverter. Gain = -1.0

In this configuration, the amplifer acts to keep the inverting input at the same voltage as the noninverting input, which is forced to zero by the switch. This can only happen if the output has the opposite polarity as the input, and the ratio of the output voltage to the input voltage is the same as the ratio of the corresponding resistors (1:1 in this case).

Comment: Yes I forgot to add (+/-) symbols. Can you explain that? How did you find the number I mean.

Answer (score 3):

In position 1 the non-inverting input is Vin, and with the negative feedback the opamp will try to make the inverting input equal to that. *Note that the equal voltage on both inputs is **not** an automatic property of an opamp, as some people seem to assume. It's true here because of the negative feedback and the very high open-loop gain of an opamp.*

So there won't be a voltage difference across the left 10 kΩ resistor, and hence, due to Ohm's Law, no current through it. Since there also doesn't go any current into the inverting input of the (ideal) opamp, there's no current through the feedback 10 kΩ resistor either, and therefore the output will be set to Vin. So \$G = \frac{Vin}{Vin}\$ = +1.

In position 2 the non-inverting input is 0 V, and the opamp will set the inverting input to 0 V as well. The current through the left 10 kΩ resistor is then \$i = \frac{Vin}{10 k\Omega}\$. That same current flows through the feedback 10 kΩ resistor, where it causes a voltage drop of

\$V_{out} = -i \cdot 10 k\Omega = -\frac{Vin}{10 k\Omega} \cdot 10 k\Omega = -V_{in}\$

The minus sign is because of the direction of the current: it flows in the opposite direction of the voltage difference we want to determine, between output and inverting input. So then \$G = -1\$.